# NLTK corpus preprocessing

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to remove sentences from corpus which are longer(>25 tokens) and shorter(<4 tokens) and also remove sentence that contains rare words that appears less than 8 times. I am trying to remove it but I get error message or empty list every time I tried. corpus is Brown corpus.

```
lens = [w for w in corpus.sents() if len(w)>=25 and len(w)<= 4]
```

I get empty list as output

```
out: []
```

I am also not sure how to include rare word in this list comprehension. Do I have to convert into FreqDist??

how to remove sentences that are very long, very short and have rare words ? I am confused. Does anyone know and can explain how to do it?? it will be much appreciated :)

Comment: `len(w)>=25 and len(w)<= 4` - you can't have a word whose length is less than 4 _and_ greater than 25 _at the same time_.

Comment: I think you meant something like `lens = [w for w in corpus.sents() if 4 <= len(w) <= 25]`

Comment: @ForceBru oh okay, how to do it then? do it separately ?? also how to include rare words less than 8 times?

Comment: @ yudhiesh is ```4 <= len(w) <= 25``` or ```4 > len(w) > 25``` though I get empty list again for the second one.

Comment: @jay.andrea `4 > len(w) > 25` is lengths of w that are greater than 4 and 25 which is not possible. `4 <= len(w) <= 25` keeps the words that are less than 25 and greater than 4 which is what you are looking for.

Comment: @yudhiesh oohh I got it now. :) thanks. but how can I also include rare words that appear less than 8 times in a sentence? ``` rare = [i for i in lens if i <= 10] ``` I got this error ``` not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int ``` which is right, since "lens" is a list. how can I put all together? any suggestion?

Comment: I added two methods that work please do accept and upvote them. On removing the rare words in a sentence you should open another questions for that. I can try and answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so where you only keep the words that have a length of `less than 26` and a length of `more than 3`.

```
a = ["hello world", "how are you doing","where are you going?", "welcome to the greatest show on earth! How will you manage to gain all the experience needed for this to show?","hi"]
[len(w) for w in a]
>>>[11, 17, 20, 110,2]
```

#### Method 1:

```
list(filter(lambda x: 4 <= len(x) <= 25, a))
>>>['hello world', 'how are you doing', 'where are you going?']
```

#### Method 2:

```
[x for x in a if 4 <= len(x) <= 25]
>>>['hello world', 'how are you doing', 'where are you going?']
```